# play framework 2.5.9 classNotFound exception for logback Filter on startup

Tags: playframework, guice, logback, playframework-2.5

I'm writing my own Filter class for logback as shown [here](https://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/filters/SampleFilter.html). I am then calling it in logback.xml like this:

`<filter class="utils.LogbackFilter" />`

I converted the sample Java code to Scala and Injected the class (the injection part was what I thought was the problem originally). My code is below:

```
class LogbackFilter @Inject() extends Filter[ILoggingEvent] {

  override def decide(event: ILoggingEvent): FilterReply = {
    if (event.getLoggerName.contains("access")) {
      FilterReply.ACCEPT
    } else {
      FilterReply.DENY
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I compile and run this Play Framework project, I get:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - 
Could not create component [filter] of type [utils.LogbackFilter] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utils.LogbackFilter
```

There is a LogbackFilter.class in:

`website-2016/target/scala-2.11/classes/utils`

I cannot figure out if this is a logback issue, a guice issue, a Play issue or what.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted, Stackoverflow showed some related questions, [one of which had the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845135/play-framework-logback-custom-layout?rq=1).

Instead of starting up Play with `activator run` I tried `activator start` and it worked. I'll leave this up here for posterity.

Comment: Shouldnt it be possible to run the app via "run" (compared to "start") and still get a working logger?